# Origin of the whistling sound when things fall

Tags: sound-effects

When objects fall in cartoons they often make a whistling sound. It seems to have spread to video games and even some live action movies.

What is the origin of this sound? Things don't generally whistle in real life when they fall.

Comment: I can't unsee Coyote falling now.

Comment: Rocks falling from >200m height kind of whistle. They make quite some noise while they fall and it’s really scary.

Comment: Known in the trade as the Wilhelm Whistle.

Answer (score 65):

Because in WW2, the Germans attached actual whistles to bombs as a [psychological tactic.](https://www.scienceabc.com/eyeopeners/why-do-bombs-make-a-whistling-sound-when-they-fall.html)

> When you are watching a Hollywood reenactment of a famous World War 2 battle, the whistling cries of falling bombs certainly help to build tension, but there is some truth behind this terrifying sound. During World War II, the Germans designed their bombs with a special whistle that would make that screaming cry as they fell towards the cities below. Typically, a metal object with sharp edges, like a bomb would make a small noise “hissing” sound as it fell through the air, unless it happened to exceed the sound barrier (343 meters per second), which would result in a sonic boom.
>
> However, by designing bombs that had a whistle-like attachment, the Germans were utilizing psychological warfare as much as physical warfare. The whistle became associated with death from above, and since the bombing raids in London and other European cities were often done in the middle of the night, that wailing cry became a nightmare-inducing and anxiety-striking sound. Survivors of the London bombing still remember those haunting whistles of death from their underground shelters.

Comment: Stuka [JU19] fighters had 'screamers' in the nose too - the famous movie noise isn't fake.

Comment: Very interesting. But can you connect that to its use in cartoons?

Comment: You asked for the origin of the sound, I gave it to you. Obviously cartoons imitate real life.

Comment: The whistle of cartoon bombs falls in pitch, but I'd expect it to rise in reality because of increasing airspeed; how did it sound?

Comment: I really wonder if cartoons before ww2 never used the whistling for falling objects

Comment: @AntonSherwood If you're above it, then the Doppler effect might decrease the frequency.

Comment: @Acccumulation in particular, if the bomb is falling some distance away the Doppler effect will make it seem to decrease in pitch as it falls, much as the pitch of a siren seems to drop in pitch as the vehicle passes you. This means that someone about to be hit by the bomb won't hear the change in pitch. (Realising this made me sad.)

Comment: @user I remember 99% invisible had [an episode](https://99percentinvisible.org/episode/classic-cartoon-sound-effects/transcript/) that discussed this and other cartoon sounds. If I recall correctly, they provided some historical detail, not about how the whistling-bomb sound was "discovered" by cartoon artists, but why it and other "sound tropes" are used in so many productions

Comment: @Tetsujin the name was Jericho Trumpet or Jericho Horn (Jericho-Trompeten in German), because it was likened to the end of days and strongly implied the listener's imminent death.  Was also the JU87, never heard of a JU19.

Comment: @Criggie - yeah, 87… no idea where 19 came from. Was rushing to go out, brain fade ;)

Comment: And of course, plenty of movie depictions also use that sound (for both bombs and bombers) even for ones that _shouldn't_ have it. At this point, it's just the "falling bomb sound", and it's not going to change anytime soon. Though there are also alternatives, like "bomb coming out of nowhere" etc., for different kinds of tension.

Comment: @Nathaniel Actually, I'd think the person on the ground about to be hit by the bomb would hear the pitch *rise* as it approaches them.  But there weren't as many people who experienced that and weren't blown to bits, so the falling pitch is what got imbedded into the cultural meme-space.

Comment: @Nathaniel A dropping pitch would only be observed if the bomb is *accelerating away* from the observer (a constant speed away from the observer would result in a lower, but constant pitch). The falling pitch of a dropped bomb is what an *observer on the plane* would hear as the the bomb accelerates away from them. Anyone on the ground should hear a rising pitch since the bomb can only accelerate toward them, no matter if they are the target or far away.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie With bombs going off around you, people screaming, and air raid sirens going off, I don't think people being bombed paid attention to the falling or raising of the bomb's whistle pitch. However, if people were safely in the bomber making an observation, they would hear the dropping pitch. I think the sound was sourced from the people dropping the bombs...

Comment: @NuclearHoagie if you are on the ground some distance away from where the bomb will hit, then initially the bomb is in the sky more or less above you and is falling almost, but not quite toward you, so the Doppler effect raises its pitch. But by the time it hits the ground it's moving perpendicular to you and has no component of its velocity toward you, so it's pitch will not be raised any more. Hence you will hear a steady drop in tone between those times. It is exactly the same as when an ambulance passes you on the ground.

Comment: "Sonic boom"? To my understanding that's not exactly relevant for bombs, if they were to reach supersonic speeds, they would explode before anyone could hear the sonic boom. Not to mention an actual sonic boom requires the object in question to make significant noise in the first place (like an airplane turbine). Doesn't seem the author has a good understanding of acoustics.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Cartoons with sound only first appeared a decade before WW2, and there were very few of them.  Cartoons grew up during WW2, so there's not a lot of "before" to compare against.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I've asked a [follow-up question](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/66430/what-did-whistling-bombs-actually-sound-like) over at History.SE to try and find out what it actually sounded like.

Comment: Just to extend @Tetsujin's comment, those plane sirens were called [Jericho trumpets](https://www.warhistoryonline.com/instant-articles/trumpets-jericho-luftwaffe.html). If you know the biblical story of Jericho, it helps convey what the intention of these sirens was; i.e. to strike fear into the hearts of the opponent. The linked article also establishes that the sirens were later removed from the planes and added to the bombs (as per this answer), so it's relevant to consider the plane sirens as the original source of the sound.

Comment: "Because"? Where is the source? You give one IRL example of something that whistles when it falls, and expect (apparently not unjustifiedly, given the amount of upvotes) others to just accept it, given your comment "*You asked for the origin of the sound, I gave it to you*". Where's the connection between cartoons and falling bombs?

Answer (score 16):

Although I personally find @Paulie_D 's answer to be satisfactory regarding the historical origins of the noise, I wanted to add another response specifically relating to the noise's introduction to cartoons.

According to Mark Mangini, who was a sound designer for Hannah Barbera back in the day:

> Music and sound effects had to be performed at the same time in the
> same space. Musical instruments were used to make the effects because
> they were easy to find, and easy to manipulate. In this Tom and Jerry
> clip, the sound of a frying pan hitting Tom’s face is played by a
> cymbal crash. (cymbals)

Specifically relating to the slide-whistle noise for a falling item or bomb:

> The percussionist would probably have it as part of their kit, and it was just natural to convey going up (slide up) or down (slide down). You could manipulate them in any one of a number of ways, very quickly or very slowly.

Source: https://99percentinvisible.org/episode/classic-cartoon-sound-effects/transcript/

I would highly recommend listening to the full interview, as it's a fascinating topic.

Answer (score 10):

The knowledge predates WW2 - in 1934 the book *Biggles of the Camel Squadron* was written by WE Johns, and describes a scene in WW1, thus:

> “I wish you wouldn’t interrupt!” snarled Henry. “When I was at Thetford,
> a fool came over from Narborough, on Christmas morning, and dropped an
> empty bottle from about ten thousand feet. We didn’t know it was a
> bottle. We thought it was just the sky falling down. At first it
> **whistled**, then it shrieked, and then it——” Henry threw up his hands in
> a despairing gesture. “The din was like nothing on earth. It made more
> noise than a score of 230-pound bombs. Now, my point is this: If one
> bottle can do that, think of the noise two or three dozen bottles would
> make falling at once! I’ll bet the gunners would stick their heads in
> their dugouts when that lot started warbling. They’d go to earth like a
> lot of rabbits with a terrier around.”

So this suggests that in the Great War falling bombs made whistling noises.

Details and full text https://www.fadedpage.com/showbook.php?pid=20200803

Comment: I disagree with your reasoning. We have a fictional story about a pilot throwing bottles out of a plane as a noisemaker to frighten the enemy as a one-off stunt, and this somehow implies that real pilots of the era were using whistling bombs? The very passage you posted emphasizes that the bottles were _much louder_ than the bombs of the day.

Comment: Your passage doesn't even prove that whistling bombs existed in 1934, much less "in the Great War". Perhaps Johns remembered or heard about a real WWI incident like the one Henry describes (a pilot casually dropped a bottle out of a plane and frightened everybody), and decided to elaborate on it. More evidence is needed.

Comment: More pertinently, just because _something_ whistled while falling before WWII does not inherently mean that cartoons must've been referencing that thing.